# Darkmode Custom CSS Toggler - Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement a Dark Mode toggle on a WordPress site as per this CodePen from CSS Tricks. https://codepen.io/adhuham/pen/GRJxpQr

I know my CSS is all correct. I'm targeting `#main` instead of `body`, and it's switching based on my OS preference as I'd expect.

The button is a simple toggle as shown in the example:

```
<button class="btn-toggle">Toggle Dark-Mode</button>
```

However I keep getting an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

I've tried placing the following script in the header, and also right underneath the button, but it isn't catching the button's click no matter what.

```
const btn = document.querySelector(".btn-toggle");
const prefersDarkScheme = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)");
btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
if (prefersDarkScheme.matches) {
document.body.classList.toggle("light-theme");
} else {
document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
}
});
```

The only thing I can guess is that the `document.querySelector(".btn-toggle")` isn't the correct syntax for WordPress. Any suggestions for getting the JS to work in the header would be grand!

Comment: Are you 100% certain that the button exists in the HTML and is created before your JS code is executed?

Comment: That was my thought too - I've tried 3 different methods of deferring the JS script and none of them have resolved the issue.